# jQuery mobile - one or multiple page events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-pageshow

Almost every page in my application has it's own pageinit and pageshow function to load content and register event listeners. So since I have around 20 listeners at the end, I'm asking myself if it would be better for jqms performance to put them all together, so using

```
$(document).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
  //... choose action based on ui.nextPage
});
```

instead of

```
$(document).on('pagebshow', '#home', function(){
 //... doing stuff for this site
}
```

for every single page?